# subsetting data in a-z orderly fashion

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to subset a data into few pieces given a cutoff keyword.
Would prefer flexible sub-setting (ie cutoff varies depending on user input). In this case: two cutoff keywords resulting in three output tables. Thanks!

```
keyword_cutoff <- c("Merc 240D", "Fiat 128")
```

data input:

```
library(data.table)
tmp_mtcars <- setDT(mtcars, keep.rownames =TRUE)[]
colnames(tmp_mtcars)[1] <- "cartype"
```

desired output table #1:

```
          cartype  mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
        Mazda RX4 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
    Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
       Datsun 710 22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
   Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
          Valiant 18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
       Duster 360 14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
```

desired output table #2:

```
          Merc 240D 24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
           Merc 230 22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
           Merc 280 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
          Merc 280C 17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
         Merc 450SE 16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
         Merc 450SL 17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
        Merc 450SLC 15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
 Cadillac Fleetwood 10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
Lincoln Continental 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
  Chrysler Imperial 14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
```

desired output table #3:

```
        Fiat 128 32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
     Honda Civic 30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
  Toyota Corolla 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
   Toyota Corona 21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
Dodge Challenger 15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
     AMC Javelin 15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
      Camaro Z28 13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
Pontiac Firebird 19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
       Fiat X1-9 27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
   Porsche 914-2 26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
    Lotus Europa 30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
  Ford Pantera L 15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
    Ferrari Dino 19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
   Maserati Bora 15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
      Volvo 142E 21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
```

Comment: I'm confused what you mean my cutoff... alphabetical cutoff? or row index-bassd

Comment: why would you like to `split` a `data.table`? You can work by "chunk "of data inside a `data.table` without splitting it. Besides, your outputs does not seem to be `data.table`s so it's very confusing...

Comment: @cath `split.data.table` exists for a reason ;-)

Comment: The title needs improvement, makes no sense.

Comment: @MichaelChirico lol fair enough. But still, I feel like we're missing informations there, not sure the split way is ideal (+ the split by keywords depend on the order of data which is not something one wants usually)

Comment: Be aware, if we are setting a key on a data.table, it will change the order, then "split" idea would make little sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need a grouping variable to `split`.  This can be done by converting a logical vector (`cartype %in% keyword_cutoff`) into numeric index by taking the cumulative sum of the logical index and `split` it to a `list` of data.tables

```
lst <- split(tmp_mtcars, tmp_mtcars[, cumsum(cartype %in% keyword_cutoff)])
lst[[1]]
#             cartype  mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#1:         Mazda RX4 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#2:     Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#3:        Datsun 710 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#4:    Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#5: Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#6:           Valiant 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
#7:        Duster 360 14.3   8  360 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
```

Comment: why not just `split(tmp_mtcars, cumsum(cartype %in% keyword_cutoff))` ? Does it work differently with `data.table` ?

Comment: @RonakShah  In that case, you need `split(tmp_mtcars, cumsum(tmp_mtcars$cartype %in% keyword_cutoff))`